# Why .NET executes code on false IF statement?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have following code:

```
var dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(string.Format(string.Format("01.04.{0}", dateProperty.Value.AddYears(-1).Year))
if (object.nullablebool.HasValue ? object.nullablebool.Value : false  
&& (string == "V" || string == "N")
&& someDate.HasValue && object.SomeOtherDate.HasValue 
&& someDate.Value.Date > dateFrom.Date)
{
       >> Code
}
```

I have tested adding .Date or even specifiing exact year from the DateTime struct, but nothing worked.

When executing the code, even if

```
someDate.Value.Date > dateFrom.Date
```

equals 1700 > 2018, the code executed as if it was true, even though the debugger says it´s false.

When I removed this part from the condition, following code:

```
someDate.HasValue && object.SomeOtherDate.HasValue
```

When I made someDate null, so someDate.HasValue is false, the if statement still executes as true.

What did it fix? Taking these two conditions to another if:

```
var dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(string.Format(string.Format("01.04.{0}", dateProperty.Value.AddYears(-1).Year))
if (object.nullablebool.HasValue ? object.nullablebool.Value : false  
&& (string == "V" || string == "N"))    
{
     if (someDate.HasValue && object.SomeOtherDate.HasValue 
     && someDate.Value.Date > dateFrom.Date)
     {
          >> Code
     }
     else 
     {
          >> Code 
     }           
}
```

The code works, but it´s way too ugly. I'm running on Visual Studio 2017 Pro.
Any ideas why it behaves like that? Executing false statements?
Thanks

Comment: Side note: `object.nullablebool.HasValue ? object.nullablebool.Value : false` can be simplified into `object.nullablebool == true`

Comment: Why fromatting at all? `var dateFrom = new DateTime(dateProperty.Value.Year - 1, 4, 1);`

Comment: This has been a pretty consistent problem in the debugger, it does not always place the "current code" highlight correctly.  Makes it *look* like the statement executes.  But that is only the way it looks, it doesn't actually execute.  Actually a bug in the x64 jitter, it doesn't always report code addresses correctly.  Crappy bug, don't let it waste your time.

Comment: My guess, you need to add brackets. I think it's interpreting everything after your `:` as being the second part of the `?` inline if, meaning it simply executes if `nullablebool` is true and ignores all the rest.

Comment: Not the question, but be **careful** with that conditional operator (`?:`). It has higher priority than `&&`, so _everything_ after `:` is `false` (`false && (string == v....` will always be false).

Comment: And please don't use keywords like `string` and `object` as variable names. this is confusing.

Comment: Dude, this is a really ugly peace of Code, create a method that check all your conditions and return a bool ! this is not debugable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your if statement performs different then expected, because it is parsed different as you wouls expect.
`object.nullablebool.HasValue ? object.nullablebool.Value : false && ...` is *parsed* as `object.nullablebool.HasValue ? object.nullablebool.Value : (false && ...)`. So if `object.nullablebool` *has* a value, thats the result of the condition. To fix this you have to add parenthesis like this:

```
if ((object.nullablebool.HasValue ? object.nullablebool.Value : false )
&& (string == "V" || string == "N") 
&& someDate.HasValue && object.SomeOtherDate.HasValue 
&& someDate.Value.Date > dateFrom.Date)
{
     // if body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's *brush up* your code (please, get rid of names like `string`, `object`; change them into meanful names):

```
  // You don't want any formatting but a simple constructor
  var dateFrom = new DateTime(dateProperty.Value.Year - 1, 4, 1);    

  // object.nullablebool == true - if object.nullablebool has value and the value is true
  if (object.nullablebool == true && (string == "V" || string == "N")) {
    // if someDate.Value is null the result will be false 
    // All we have to do is to propagate the null: ?. in someDate?.Date
    if (someDate?.Date > dateFrom.Date && object.SomeOtherDate.HasValue) {
      // Code
    }
    else {  
      // Code
    }
  }
```